# How to show if $c=X'w$ has an solution, then there exists uniqu $w_0$ such that $var(w_0'Y)\leq var(w'Y)$?

Tags: self-study, linear-model, umvue

The whole question is the following:

> Consider the linear model $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{\beta}+\varepsilon,$ where $\mathbf{X}$ is a known $n \times p$ matrix, $\mathbf{\beta}$
> is a $p$ -vector of unknown parameters, and $\varepsilon$ is a random $n$ -vector whose components are independent and identically distributed with mean 0 and variance
> $\sigma^{2} .$ Let $c \in \mathbb{R}^{p} .$ Show that if the equation $c=X'w$ has a solution, then there
> is a unique solution $\mathbf{w}_{0} \in \mathbb{R}\left(\mathbf{X}'\right)$ such that $\operatorname{var}\left(\mathbf{w}_{0}' \mathbf{Y}\right) \leq \operatorname{var}\left(\mathbf{w}' \mathbf{Y}\right)$ for any
> other solution of $\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{X}' \mathbf{w}$.

---

We are told in the class that if $l\in\mathbb{R}(\mathbf{X})$ then $l'\hat{\beta}$ is the **best linear unbiased estimator** of $l'\beta$, where $l=Q'c$ for some $c$, $X=X^*Q$ such that $QQ'$ is non-singular and $rank(QQ')=r$.

In my understanding, we are interested in $l'\beta$ only because $l$ can be decomposed as $Q'c$ because $Q$ has such nice property that $QQ'$ is non-singular therefore invertible. I tried to connect the expression of $l=Q'c$ with $c=X'w$. It seems $c$ is already in $\mathbb{R}(\mathbf{X})$ by its expression, but there are multiple $w$, where's the uniqueness comes from?

Comment: Your notations are not standard and somewhat problematic. E.g. "$\mathbb{R}\left(\mathbf{X}'\right)$" is not standard notation. What does it mean? Is it "...$\mathbb{R}(X')$..." or "...$Ran(X')$..."? If it is "...$Ran(X')$...", then it should be "...$Ran(X)$...", not $X'$.

Comment: @Michael sorry $\mathbb{R}$ means the row space I believe...